# Find matching np.ndarray in list with np.ndarrays

Tags: python, list, numpy

Newbie here... I have a given np array (here "result") and want to check whether it exists in a list (here "codewords").

```
 for message in messages: 
    result = message.dot(G) % size_of_alphabet
    if result not in codewords:
        codewords.append(result)
```

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I already tried some combinations of any() but nothing worked :/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can better explain what you're trying to get from here:

```
result = message.dot(G) % size_of_alphabet
```

Comment: The value of result is a np array as mentioned. Why I´m doing that computation there would be pretty complicated to explain. All you have to know is that there are many results that are equal and I dont want to store them in codewords if they already exist since it would dramatically increase the runtime when iterating over the codeword list. Hope it helps :)

Comment: maybe the problem occurs because you're applying list functions to arrays.
if you set `result = result.tolist()` before the if statement should fix it.

something like this:

'
for message in messages: 
    result = message.dot(G) % size_of_alphabet
    result = result.tolist()
    if result not in codewords:
        codewords.append(result)
'